# Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format

Tags: regex

I want a regexp for matching time in HH:MM format. Here's what I have, and it works:

```
^[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

This matches everything from 00:00 to 23:59.

However, I want to change it so 0:00 and 1:00, etc are also matched as well as 00:00 and 01:30. I.e to make the leftmost digit optional, to match HH:MM as well as H:MM.

Any ideas how to make that change? I need this to work in javascript as well as php.

Comment: Actually your original regexp will not match a whole range of valid time values, e.g. 17:00

Comment: This works: `^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?::[0-5]\d){1,2}$` and also catches time values yours doesn't match.

Comment: @GreatAndPowerfulOz
That is correct.
Instead of [01] you could write [0-1] for uniformity, but this is not necessary, because e.g. [0-3] is exactly the same as [0123], only shorter. And because we are lazy, we always prefer the shortest variant, so we don't have to write more than absolutely necessary. The saying "time is money" applies here ;-)

Also ?:: ensures that only the whole pattern capture something and not every group as I have see in the explanation of this pattern on https://regex101.com/r/YNlvQK/1.

So today I've learn something new and therefore improve myself. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 494, accepted):

Your original regular expression has flaws: it wouldn't match `04:00` for example.

This may work better:

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Comment: This regExp is for time without leading zero. 
RegExp for time with leading zero is `^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`

Comment: @SergO please read his answer more carefully.  His answer is for both a leading zero and without.

Comment: A slightly shorter form is `^(?:\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$`

Comment: Works nicely in C# as well.

Comment: @SergO shouldn't that be ^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$  ?

Comment: don't forget the trailing and leading slashes in javascript! ;)

Comment: Just a heads up that this doesn't support 24:00 which you might want to allow otherwise nice one!

Comment: and version including seconds : `^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){1,2}$`

Comment: Shouldn't `0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3] ` be before `[0-9]`? When for example is `21` `[0-9]` will match first taking the first digit

Comment: @Martin Sorry, but why not simply `^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`? For HH:MM that is, not matching H:MM.

Comment: Please consider using `\A…\z` instead of `^…$` for input containing new lines.

Answer (score 187):

#### Regular Expressions for Time

- **HH:MM 12-hour format, optional leading 0**

  ```
  /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]$/
  ```
- **HH:MM 12-hour format, optional leading 0, mandatory meridiems (AM/PM)**

  ```
  /((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))/
  ```
- **HH:MM 24-hour with leading 0**

  ```
  /^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/
  ```
- **HH:MM 24-hour format, optional leading 0**

  ```
  /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/
  ```
- **HH:MM:SS 24-hour format with leading 0**

  ```
  /(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)/
  ```

**[Reference and Demo](https://digitalfortress.tech/tips/top-15-commonly-used-regex/)**

Comment: Any reason **HH:MM 24-hour with leading 0** is not `^([0-2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]+$`?

Comment: Because the regex in the answer works well. And the one you commented works too. Feel free to use either of them. :)

Comment: For people matching 12 hours (with am/pm) strings with the above regex, keep in mind that testing "13:00 PM" against the regex will return true (some values) because "3:00 PM" part in the string is valid. I resolved the issue by using the following if statement 

let res = value.match(regex); if (res && res[0] === value) doSomething();

Comment: does the trailing `\d` in the first example belong there?  seems like that would only match 3-digit minutes.

Comment: yep, you are right. it should be either `[0-9]` or `\d` but not both to avoid matching 3 digit minutes. Answer is updated.

Comment: Why not simply `^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$` for HH:MM 24 hour with leading 0? I mean, why do we need `0[0-9]|1[0-9]` instead of `[0-1][0-9]` there?

Comment: With regex, there are multiple ways to get the same results. Feel free to use whichever seems the easiest/most readable to you ;)

Comment: @VladMacovei your answer is not working for me try: 14:000 it matches the regex (at least in python 3.7.12 using re library).

Comment: @dantebarba I've tried it on regex101.com and it works. The outcome depends on the initial string. if you are searching in a longer string and want to extract a valid hour somewhere in the middle try `([0-2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]{1})`. I think i used the previous regex to validate a imput box and that is why i used `^` (starts with) and `$` (ends with). I highly recommend using a regex playground to try out expressions.

Comment: what if I have the time format between more words? like *time is **12:34** is rainy* outside

Comment: Its quite simple, you only need to only remove the start/end of string regex (i.e. `(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]`). Tested for HH:MM 24-hour with leading 0

Comment: Please don't make everything in your answer bold text.

Comment: @MichaelM. thank you for your suggestion. I would like to kindly decline it since I prefer leaving the title in bold for better visibility/readability. Good day :)

Comment: What about 24:00, not valid or just 24 hours in a day? Of course equals the next day at 00:00.

Comment: @Harm, AFAIK, 24:00 is not valid. After 23:59, you get 00:00 which represents the beginning of the next day (you are right to say that 24:00 == 00:00), but in programming, we use only 00:00 to denote the end of the current day as well as the beginning of the next day.

Answer (score 56):

None of the above worked for me.
In the end I used:

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$ (js engine)
```

**Logic:**

The first number (hours) is either:
 a number between 0 and 19 --> `[0-1]?[0-9]` (allowing single digit number)
 or
 a number between 20 - 23 --> `2[0-3]`

the second number (minutes) is always a number between 00 and 59 --> `[0-5][0-9]` (not allowing a single digit)

Comment: You don't need the dash in first square bracket, `[01]` works just as well ;)

Comment: Here's this answer revised to only accept 12 hour time (including optional leading zeros): `^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]$`

Comment: `^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$` to force a leading zero

Answer (score 11):

You can use this one 24H, seconds are optional

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$
```

Answer (score 6):

The best would be for HH:MM without taking any risk.

```
^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Comment: could this be shortened to `^([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$`?

Answer (score 5):

Amazingly I found actually all of these don't quite cover it, as they don't work for shorter format midnight of 0:0 and a few don't work for 00:00 either, I used and tested the following:

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]?[0-9]$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regular expression:

```
^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([1-5]{1}[0-9])$
```

If you want to exclude 00:00, you can use this expression

```
^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):(0[1-9]{1}|[1-5]{1}[0-9])$
```

Second expression is better option because valid time is 00:01 to 00:59 or 0:01 to 23:59. You can use any of these upon your requirement.
[Regex101 link](http://regex101.com/r/mN1iT5/16)

Comment: The first expression does not accept 00: **05** . But thanks. Leads me to the validation I was looking for.

Comment: neither the first nor the second regex match `04:00` did I make something wrong, check this [DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/64b569f063a7).

Answer (score 2):

As you asked the left most bit optional, I have done left most and right most bit optional too, check it out

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]?$
```

It matches with

```
0:0 
00:00
00:0 
0:00
23:59
01:00
00:59
```

The live link is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/QVbb8w/1/)

Answer (score 2):

### Description

`hours:minutes` with:

- Mandatory `am|pm` or `AM|PM`
- Mandatory leading zero `05:01` instead of `5:1`
- Hours from `01` up to `12`
- Hours does not accept `00` as in `00:16 am`
- Minutes from `00` up to `59`

`01:16 am` ✅
`01:16 AM` ✅
`01:16` ❌ (misses `am|pm`)
`01:16 Am`❌ (`am` must *all* be either lower or upper case)
`1:16 am` ❌ (Hours misses leading zero)
`00:16` ❌ (Invalid hours value `00`)

### Regular Expression

To match single occurrence:
`^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]) ((a|p)m|(A|P)M)$`

To match multiple occurrences:
Remove `^` `$`
`(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]) ((a|p)m|(A|P)M)`

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me, the following one worked.

```
"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"
```

Comment: This allows invalid time like "31:123" though

Comment: You can use this solution then https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536768/4676291

Comment: This match the invalid & unmatch the valid check this [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/890a28647780).

Answer (score 1):

To validate **24h** time, use:

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2?[0-3]|[0-9])[:\-\/]([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])$
```

This accepts:

```
22:10
2:10
2/1
...
```

But does not accept:

```
25:12
12:61
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex:

```
^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$|^[2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$|^[2][3]:[0][0]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The below regex will help to validate hh:mm format

```
^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
private static final String TIME24HOURS_PATTERN = "([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]";

public boolean validate(final String time) {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(TIME24HOURS_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(time);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

This method return "true" when String match with the Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to [Manish M Demblani's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29921396/2657515) contribution above
handles  4am 
(I got rid of the seconds section as I don't need it in my application)

```
^(([0-1]{0,1}[0-9]( )?(AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm))|(([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]( )?(AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm))|(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]))$
```

handles:
4am
4 am
4:00
4:00am
4:00 pm
4.30 am
 etc..

Comment: `AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm` = `[AaPp][Mm]`

Answer (score 0):

> Your code will not work properly as it will not work for 01:00 type formats. You can modify it as follows.

```
pattern =r"^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]$"
```

> Making it less complicated we can use a variable to define our hours limits.Further we can add meridiems for more accurate results.

```
hours_limit = 12 
pattern = r"^[1-hours_limit]:[0-5][0-9]\s?[AaPp][Mm]$"
print(re.search(pattern, "2:59 pm"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]?[0-9]|5[0-9])$/
```

Answer (score -1):

Mine is:

`^(1?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`

This is much shorter

Got it tested with several example

Match:

- 00:00
- 7:43
- 07:43
- 19:00
- 18:23

And doesn't match any invalid instance such as 25:76 etc ...

Comment: `09:30` do not match

Comment: Your own examples 00:00 and 07:43 are not matching.

Answer (score -1):

check this [masterfull timestamp detector](http://regexr.com/395v5) regex I built to look for a user-specified timestamp, examples of what it will pickup include, but is most definitely NOT limited to;

```
8:30-9:40
09:40-09 : 50
09 : 40-09 : 50
09:40 - 09 : 50
08:00to05:00
08 : 00to05 : 00
08:00 to 05:00
8am-09pm
08h00 till 17h00
8pm-5am
08h00,21h00
06pm untill 9am
```

It'll also pickup many more, as long as the times include digits

Comment: `RegExr requires a modern browser. Please update your browser to the latest version and try again.` ... I can't even see it ... :-/

Comment: I re-wrote this a tiny bit using non-capturing groups to make matches easier to isolate. https://regex101.com/r/424USF/1 '/(\d{1,2}\s{0,2}(?:am|pm|(?:[-|:|h| ]\s{0,2}\d{1,2}\s{0,2})?)\s{0,2})(-|to|till|,|until)(\s{0,2}\d{1,2}\s{0,2}(?:am|pm|(?:[-|:|h| ]\s{0,2}\d{1,2}\s{0,2})?))/gmi'

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following

```
^\d{1,2}([:.]?\d{1,2})?([ ]?[a|p]m)?$
```

It can detect the following patterns :

```
2300 
23:00 
4 am 
4am 
4pm 
4 pm
04:30pm 
04:30 pm 
4:30pm 
4:30 pm
04.30pm
04.30 pm
4.30pm
4.30 pm
23:59 
0000 
00:00
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the following

```
^([0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9])|(0?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])$
```

Note: I was assuming the javascript regex engine.  If it's different than that please let me know.

Answer (score -3):

You can use following regex :

```
^[0-2]?[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

Only modification I have made is leftmost digit is optional. Rest of the regex is same.