# Need regex for matching HH:MM and HHMM time format

Tags: .net, regex

I am saving time in a sheet which can store values between `00:00` to `23:59` and `0000` to `2359`. However the regex i have used is not working. Any value which is less the `10:00` hours, e.g., `9:00` it does not work. I realized that its buggy and not upto the mark can anyone help with a proper regex or fix this one:

```
^(([0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-9][0-5][0-9])|([0-2][0-3][0-5][0-9])|([0-1][0-9][0-5][0-9])|([0-5][0-9])|([0-9]))$
```

Note i need to be able to enter values without colon as well.

Comment: Note i need to be able to enter values without colon as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with that seems to match your own attempt is something like this:

```
^(?:2[0-3]|[0-1]?[0-9])?:?[0-5]?[0-9]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9VeCmOMb3mZxS9Ej)

It seems you want to allow both a single and a double digit entry (counting as minutes i guess, since double digits allowed are 00 to 59) which Michal's answer doesn't take into account. But Anirudh's solution may be the best one. But that depends on your needs I guess.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the demo link. This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use regex..You can use TimeSpan

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(input,"hh:mm",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Throws exception if input is not in `hh:mm` format

---

Though in your regex you are missing `[0-9](:\d{1,2})?`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify answer from [Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format) to

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):?[0-5][0-9]$
```

Which looks like this

[image: Regexp to match the datetime]

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one :

```
([0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-1][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])|(^[0-9]:[0-9]+)
```