# javascript validation for input time in format hh:mm a

Tags: javascript

I want to make user enter time in format "hh:mma" or "hh:mm a". I want to leave it to user the choice to enter space between mm & a. 
What can be the regular expression for this ?

Comment: now using /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(:00)?([apAP][mM])?$/;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put space in the pattern where I required space and if worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use `?` to make the preceding token optional, for example `/colou?r/` matches `color` and `colour`. If you are struggling with the hh:mm part of the regex, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(([0-1]?[0-9])|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9] ?(am|pm|AM|PM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]?[0-9])\s?(am|pm)
```