# Ruby strptime with greater than 24 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, strptime

I have a string of the following format:

```
"136:16:11.862504" 
(hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds)
```

Whenever I try to use Ruby's strptime to parse this string, it throws an `ArgumentError: invalid strptime format - '%H:%M:%S'`

I've actually searched quite extensively and cannot figure out an elegant way to parse this (besides the rather clunky solution of splitting the string by its colons and periods, and doing it all manually). Is there a way of doing this that I'm overlooking?

EDIT: I'm not looking to get a timestamp out of this, I'm looking to get a time **duration**.

Comment: What's your expected output? I believe strptime always expects a time that fits into a standard M/D/Y H:M style. If you're just trying to break this into hours/minutes/seconds components, the `Time` class may not be your best choice.

Comment: Can you toss or round the milliseconds?

Comment: Pure core Ruby wouldn't handle this.. Take a look https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Comment: @ArupRakshit Even Chronic will return `nil` when trying to parse this.

Comment: First of all `Time` class Don't have `:strptime` method. Other Date or DateTime class wouldn't able to handle this, as Date part is missing, mostly.. `136` is not a *valid hour*. It is probably a *duration*. So I thought that Gem will help, although I didn't try.

Comment: chronic_duration might help

Comment: @ArupRakshit `Time` does have a strptime method, but it's in stdlib, not corelib, so you have to `require 'time'` first. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/index.html

Comment: @DylanMarkow Oopps.. Then it should work I think. I was searching here - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime. Confusing :-)

Comment: dave, what blocks you from using regexp?

Comment: @BradWerth I don't care about the milliseconds. Does that help?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ good idea. what would that regex look like?

Comment: @davepaola you could use something based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your expected output? '136' is not a valid hour, and since you don't have a date portion, we can't simply turn those 'extra' hours into days. If you don't care about the date portion, this solution may work for you:

```
time = "136:16:11.862504"
hours, minutes, seconds = time.split(":").map(&:to_f)
hours %= 24
minutes %= 60
seconds %= 60

Time.new(0, 1, 1, hours, minutes, seconds, 0)
=> 0000-01-01 16:16:11 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if nothing blocks you from using `Regexp`, you could use something based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format) answer, for example:

```
/^(\d+):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])\.\d+$/ =~ "136:16:11.862504"
puts "#{$1} : #{$2} : #{$3}"
136 : 16 : 11
```