# PHP wrong result of strtotime

Tags: php

time `"24:14"` is not valid time and this should be `"00:14"` for correct valid time but `strtotime` return `CORRECT` and its wrong.

```
    if(strtotime("24:14")) {
        echo "CORRECT<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "NOT CORRECT<br/>";
    }
```

[codepad link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/R3iih0)

Comment: strtotime returns a numeric value, not true or false. RTFM

Comment: @r3wt Well, he could make a comparison against false (!== false), since strtotime returns integer or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strtotime uses standard PHP time format. As you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) "24" is a valid string for hours from PHP 5.3.0.

You can use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536768/835146) to check that time, for example:

```
function time_check($t) {
    $reg = '/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/';
    if ( preg_match($reg, $t) ) 
       echo "CORRENT\n";
    else
       echo "WRONG\n";
}

$check_ok = "01:22";
$check_no = "24:11";

time_check($check_ok);
time_check($check_no);
```

Comment: for `00:00:01` or `00:00:00` return false

Comment: Yes, check the link, it's only for HH:MM format, you can simply add also seconds: ^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])$

Comment: It's already optional, I change [0-5][0-9] in ([0-5][0-9]|[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]) ;-)

Comment: thanks sir. how to check time is `time 12` or `time 24` in your this pattern? can i seperator this action for detect time is 12 or 24?

Answer (score 0):

You're confused.

strtotime doesn't return true or false. it returns a timestamp, which is a truthy value or false on error.

quoting from the manual:

> Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise. Previous to PHP 5.1.0, this function would return -1 on failure.

Reference -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

Because it returns false on error, you need to compare it to false

```
if(strtotime("24:14") !== false) {
    //Correct
} else {
    //Not correct
}
```