# Regular expression for matching HH:MM or HH or H time format

Tags: regex

I have php web application and use preg_match parse the several times out of a string.

The problem is that my users may enter the times in the following formats:

- "from 8:30 to 17:00"
- "8 to 18"
- "09:00 to 14:30"

So basically I want to get two times out of a string and each of those two times may either be given in H, HH or HH:MM.

There is a stackoverflow thread just for HH:MM, but ([Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)) but none for my problem.

Comment: Or those your only allowed, fixed formats, or are these examples of what users enter? English only, or other languages as well?

Comment: I am not if this you needed. `preg_match("/((2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]))|(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]))|([0-5][0-9])/", $foo)`

Comment: For anyone that downvotes, I would be glad to receive a small comment, on why.

Comment: @Wrikken: The user can enter the time however she/he wants, but the examples I mentioned are the only formats they my users are using so far.

Comment: @PascalKlein: I don't think the downvotes are fair, I can think of 2 reasons: (1) you don't show your current effort before you've asked SO, and (2) this isn't something that regexes are quite suited to, as the possibilities of adding times are endless. If you want to keep the input totally format-less, you're going to have a tough time coming up with something acceptable at first, and will be haunted by 'bug'-reports for a long time to come. There's a reason people tend to go for structured from & to hours & minutes inputs, it makes sense both financially and reliability wise.

Comment: @Wrikken: Thanks, but both points you mention make sense. I will take more time into drafting the question next time

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer (could possibly be tidied up) :
`(\d\d?(?::\d\d)?)\s+to\s+(\d\d?(?::\d\d)?)`

See [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/lL9yG5/1)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Without any control, it's up to you to validate the times later:

```
^\D*(\d\d?(?::\d\d)?)\D+(\d\d?(?::\d\d)?)\D*$
```

You can, of course, test that hour is between 0 and 23 and minute between 0 and 59:

```
^\D*((?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?)\D+((?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?))\D*$
```