# Javascript regular expression to validate time format "09:15 AM"

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, html

I tried with the following regular expression but it is not working as expected.

```
/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]{2}(AM|PM)/
```

Comment: You can try `/^\d{2}:\d{2}(A|P)M$/i`

Comment: If you are foloowing 24 hour clock, why are you using AM/PM in the forst place. Try with `/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](A|P)M/`

Comment: propbably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format

Comment: This is also not working.

Comment: @PradeepChalla Add the input string, and the JS code to extract date from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this regex:

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kZ1iT0/2)**

Comment: `[APap][mM]` why not `i` flag. Also missing `$` anchor

Comment: thanks  @Rahul I changed as per tushar comments and working fine /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) (A|P)M$/i

Comment: @PradeepChalla:- You are  welcome Yes you can change to make it more compact.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
/^[1-12]:[0-59](A|P)M$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing space before AM|PM and there is unnecessary `{2}`
The following changes works for me:

```
^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)
```

On the string

```
09:15 AM
```