# How to validate user input for this Java code?

Tags: java, validation, input

I would like to have a validation for: number input only, hour must be <=24, minutes must be <60, and the user must type the ':' sign between hh:mm.

```
 int total; //Total Minutes
    String time; //Input from keyboard


    final Scanner T = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the time in HH:MM :");
    time = T.next();

    //Get the value before the ':'
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, time.indexOf(':')));


    //Get the value after the ':'
    int minute =Integer.parseInt (time.substring((time.indexOf(':') + 1), time.length()));


    //Formula of the calculation
    total = hour * 60 + minute;


    //Display the final value
    System.out.println( time +" is " + total + " minutes.");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)

Comment: You wouldn't want a time 24:53 now, do you? So why <= 24 and not <24? Also, is a single digit hour permitted?

Comment: sorry the <= my mistake but the format must be hh:mm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow your format, the user must enter a time with ':' at the 3rd character position `charAt(2)` and the rest of the characters (at indices 0, 1, 3 and 4) must be digits. A very quick to implement and good to learn solution is to use regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

However, I'll be showing you a simpler to understand solution using your code as a template:

1. Verify that the length is 5
2. Verify that the hours are correct
3. Verify that the minutes are correct
4. Ask the user to re-enter the value if anything is incorrect

Here's the code:

```
    int total; // Total Minutes
    String time; // Input from keyboard

    final Scanner T = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the time in HH:MM :");
    time = T.next();

    boolean correctFormat = false;
    int hour = 0, minute = 0;

    while (!correctFormat) {
        correctFormat = true;

        if (time.length() != 5)
            correctFormat = false;
        else {

            // Get the value before the ':'
            hour = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2));
            if (hour >= 24 || hour < 0)
                correctFormat = false;

            // Get the value after the ':'
            minute = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3, 5));
            if (minute >= 60 || minute < 0)
                correctFormat = false;
        }
        if (!correctFormat) {
            System.out.print("Pleaase follow the format! Enter the time in HH:MM :");
            time = T.next();
        }

    }

    // Formula of the calculation
    total = hour * 60 + minute;

    // Display the final value
    System.out.println(time + " is " + total + " minutes.");
```

Further, if you want to make the code even more robust, you can check to see if the user actually enters numbers before and after the ':' by catching a 'NumberFormatException' that will be thrown from the `Integer.parseInt()` method if the parameters aren't an actual number. You can do this by editing the above code to as follows:

```
    int total; // Total Minutes
    String time; // Input from keyboard

    final Scanner T = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the time in HH:MM :");
    time = T.next();

    boolean correctFormat = false;
    int hour = 0, minute = 0;

    while (!correctFormat) {
        correctFormat = true;

        if (time.length() != 5)
            correctFormat = false;
        else {
            try {
                hour = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2));
                minute = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3, 5));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                correctFormat = false;
            }
            if (correctFormat) {
                if (hour >= 24 || hour < 0)
                    correctFormat = false;

                if (minute >= 60 || minute < 0)
                    correctFormat = false;
            }
        }
        if (!correctFormat) {
            System.out.print("Pleaase follow the format! Enter the time in HH:MM :");
            time = T.next();
        }
    }

    // Formula of the calculation
    total = hour * 60 + minute;

    // Display the final value
    System.out.println(time + " is " + total + " minutes.");
```

Comment: This isn't really validating since your code runs into an exception due to invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

For validating, use a regular expression:

```
time.matches( "(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]" )
```

To convert, simply use

```
int hour = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2));
int minute = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3));
```