# Used strict and warning but still no error messages when there is supposed to be a mistake somewhere

Tags: regex, perl

I have a program that basically opens and reads the syslog in ubuntu and use a keyword text file to search for specific words in the syslog and have that to be outputted into an output text file. Problem is, it was all going well until I can't seem to get any errors anymore which doesn't really help me as there is a mistake somewhere which makes me not see any output at all. I ran my regex using a perl online testing tool and it works but doesnt seem so when I try to run it on the terminal. I would be glad if someone could help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;  
use warnings;

my $syslogFile = 'syslog';
open (my $syslogInfo, '<', $syslogFile) or die "Could not open $syslogFile";

my $keywordFile = 'keyword';
open (my $keywordInfo, '<', $keywordFile) or die "Could not open $keywordFile";

while (my $line = <$syslogInfo>)
{

    if($line =~ m/[a-zA-Z]\s(\d{1-31})\s(\d{1-24}):(\d{1-59}):(\d{1-59})\s[a-zA-Z]\s($keywordInfo).\ni/)
    {
        open(outputFile, ">>output");

        flock(outputFile, 2);

        print outputFile "$line\n";
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is a sample of what is in the syslog

Dec 29 22:02:28 osboxes NetworkManager[686]:     plen 24 (255.255.255.0)

Comment: Your regex doesn't look correct at all. For starters, the first element is for one and only one alphabetical character. I would recommend running your regex through an online tester to make sure it works, such as [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: `$keywordInfo` is a filehandle... but the rest of your regex is bonkers as well.

Comment: Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format) to see a regex to check times.

Comment: @AntonH Thank you very much for that website helped a lot! But another question though since I cannot find it in the book. How do you add a textfile or string into the regex?

Comment: Your shebang line is missing a slash. Should be `#!/usr/bin/perl`

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Ok i fixed my regex by doing this:    /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\s[a-zA-Z]*\sNetworkManager.*/s   But it still doesn't seem to output anything nor give me any error . (PS. I placed NetworkManager as a test to see if there's an output)

Comment: What's `2`? Exclusive lock? Use `LOCK_EX` exported from Fcntl instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You include `$keywordInfo` in your regex. But `$keywordInfo` is a filehandle, which means that, when stringified, it will look like "GLOB(0x1819f30)". I suspect that's not the string that you're looking for.

You know how to read data from a filehandle. You're doing that with your other filehandle, `$syslogInfo`. So you just need to do that with this filehandle too. Something like this:

```
my $string_to_find = <$keywordInfo>;
chomp $string_to_find;

# Now use $string_to_find in your regex.
```

Comment: Oh that helped a lot. Got it working now thank you very much Dave!