# Regex: check multiple times in one string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey I need a regex for the following cases:

```
- von 08:00-12:00uhr und 12:00-22:00 uhr
- von 08:00-12:00 uhr 
- von 08:00-12:00 uhr
- von 08:00-12:00
- 08:00-12:00
```

so the regex should handle input like that:

```
(von)?_?0?[0-23]:[00-59]_?(Uhr|uhr)?((bis)?_?0?[0-23]:[00-59]_?(Uhr|uhr))?
```

I tried a lot but the best match after reading in the wiki was:

```
(von)?([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$(uhr|Uhr)?((und)?(von)?([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$)
```

Can you give me an advise how i can handle this problem? Is the way i test the Dateformat right?

Comment: How do you think spaces work in regex?

Comment: I'd advise to use blocks in a constructor notation. The [`/^-\s*(?:von)?\s*(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):?(?:[0-5]\d)(?:-(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):?(?:[0-5]\d))?\s*(?:uhr)?\s*(?:und (?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):?(?:[0-5]\d)(?:-(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):?(?:[0-5]\d))?\s*(?:uhr)?\s*)?$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/jZ0hM4/1) seems too scary :)

Comment: @Biffen i think spaces are \s... arent they? for testing i worte the string without spaces. sorry i should mention it in the question.

Comment: @dr_debug It won't work if you don't handle the spaces one way or another (and an `_` is not a space). Even if you're just testing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ty, i'll read sth about contructor notation

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tyvm thats prettier than the most other solutions.

Comment: Yes, but you already accepted an answer. I do not want to mess with other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

`(von )?([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d-([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d( ?uhr)?( und ([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d-([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d( ?uhr)?)?`

Spaces are matched by an actual space character, `\s` matches not just the ascii space, but most kinds of whitespace (e.g. also tabs).

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
/([0-2]\d:[0-5]\d\-[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d)/g
```

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/eD0hY1/1

You are only interested in the times, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your first example is an error and it should be

> von 08:00-12:00 uhr und 12:00-22:00 uhr

instead of

> von 08:00-12:00uhr und 12:00-22:00 uhr

This is a quick solution I came up with. There is a place for improvement though, using the space character instead of ' ' (space).

`(von )?(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]( uhr)?( und (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9] uhr)?`

Note: the solution is based on the top voted answer on 
[Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)