# Regex to allow a user to type in a time - C#

Tags: c#, regex, textbox

Lots of other questions give answers for regex expressions which only allow fully completed times like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536768/3075190): `^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`

But this is no use in a `Textbox.TextChanged` event because while typing `15:45` the textbox will contain `15:` which doesn't match the expression above.

Is there an easy way to allow a partial match of a Regex expression to ensure a half typed time still passes or would I have to break the expression down into its parts all separated out by `or`s, like [this](http://regexr.com/3gco1)?

Comment: Are you looking for `MaskedTextBox`?

Comment: You can manually adjust the pattern to use optional groups, like https://regex101.com/r/BYpaYS/1

Comment: That's perfect @WiktorStribiżew - if you post it as an answer I'll accept it?

Comment: It's more traditionally done like `^(?:(?:[01][0-9]?|2[0-3]?)(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]?)?)?)?$` otherwise you lose track of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may manually adjust such patterns to allow partial matches. One thing to remember is that they are only good for *live validation*, not *final* validation. To perform final validation, you need to use a complete pattern with no optional parts (or just those obligatory optional parts).

So, the technique consists in using nested optional [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon), like `(?:...(?:...)?)?`.

```
^(?:(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]?)?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BYpaYS/1/)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group

  - `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group

    - `[01]?[0-9]` - an optional `0` or `1` and then any 1 digit
    - `|` - or
    - `2[0-3]` - `2` and then a digit from `0` to `3`
  - `)` - end of an optional non-capturing group
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group

  - `:`  - a colon
  - `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group

    - `[0-5][0-9]?` - a digit from `0` to `5` and then any optional digit
  - `)?` - end of an optional non-capturing group
  - `)?` - end of an optional non-capturing group
- `)?` - end of an optional non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.