# Regex to ensure input starts with +/- then number, or is an hour in hh:mm format

Tags: regex

I need a regex in a form in order to make sure the input either:

- starts with + or - and then has numbers (for instance: +120 or -15)
- or is an exact hour, for instance: 17:20 or 15:23

The regex I came up with is:

```
^[+-][\d]*|[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}$
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly: each expression works separately `(^[+-][\d]*$` or `^[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}$)` but together with the | operator, it allows the input `+120sds` where it didn't when the expression was tested separately.

Comment: Group it. `^(?:[+-]\d+|\d{2}:\d{2})$`

Comment: Side note: when posting questions, there's no need to add a signature, advance thanks, explicit pleas for help, regards, salutations, etc. These things have been removed from several of your questions - if you can refrain from adding this material, it will leave volunteers with more time to edit questions from new users. Thanks!

Comment: OK sorry, I won't add these anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the alternatives, e.g. using a non-capturing alternation group `(?:...|...)`. That way, both the anchors will apply to all the alternatives. Also, to match time in 24h format, you may use a more precise expression, `(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]` (also, see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)).

```
^(?:[+-]\d+|(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$
  ^^       ^                               ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWqBpI/1/). Note that it seems there must be at least 1 digit after `+` and `-`, thus, use `\d+` instead of `\d*`.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
  -`(?:` - start of the grouping construct

  - `[+-]` - a `+` or `-`
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `|` - or

  - `(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])` - `00` to `23`
  - `:` - a colon
  - `[0-5][0-9]` - `00` to `59`
- `)` - end of the alternation group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: your regexp fails when the hour is like `1:14` instead of `01:14`. To fix it you should use: `^(?:[+-]\d+|(?:[01]{0,1}[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$`

Comment: @marco I just follow OP requirement, the format is `HH:mm`, see the original regex - `[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}`. If it should work with another format, let OP change the requirements. Actually, [**it will suffice to put `?` after `[01]`**](https://regex101.com/r/DWqBpI/2) and use `^(?:[+-]\d+|(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$` if the hour part can consist of just 1 digit.

Comment: oh, yes, I see.

Comment: Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew ! And yes, it has to fail when input is like `1:14`