# Why isn't my time replacing regex working?

Tags: python, regex

The kind of sentences expected :

I will be there at `4:15` later today

I will be there at `14:06` later today.

Few things to notice there:

1- The hour format is 24h

2- The hour can be one letter or 2 while the minutes is always 2.

3- The time is always mid sentence .

what i have tried :

```
import re

response = re.sub(r'^(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|24:00)$',
                                     '7:15', 'I will be there at `4:15` later today')
```

I also tried this regex `^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$`
and it also didn't work.

Comment: You are applying start/end of the string anchors, but try to match from the middle of a larger string. That can't work.

Comment: I tried removing them and also didn't work.

Comment: `4` is not covered by `[01]`. Additionally, get rid of the anchors.

Comment: The first digit should be optional , so `(([01]*\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|24:00)` will do. Also remove the begin/end anchors.

Comment: Ok can you kindly add the adjustments or final code in answers so i can properly test, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues here but this works:

```
import re

response = re.sub(r'(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)|24:00', '7:15', 'I will be there at `4:15` later today')
print(response)
```

This yields

```
I will be there at `7:15` later today
```

You need to get rid of the anchors and make `[01]` optional with a `?`. Lastly, change the parentheses to non-capturing and remove non-necessary parentheses.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)|24:00','7:15','I will be there at 55:55 later today)` Will result in `I will be there at 57:15 later today`

Comment: @GarbageCollector: That's totally true.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different regex: `(0*[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]|24:00`, which is an adapted version of [Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)

```
import re
response = re.sub(r'(0*[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]|24:00',
                 '7:15', 
                 'I will be there at `4:15` later today')
print(response)
```

In your given example the time is always placed inside two `. If this is always the case for the given time you could simplify the regex to

```
import re
response = re.sub(r'`.+`',
                 '7:15', 
                 'I will be there at `24:00` later today')
print(response)
```

Comment: Gave this format 015:20 which is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: @Xufox, thanks for the hint I adapted the given case

Comment: @user9127040 I adapted my solution can you validate it again.

Comment: With your first regex `I will be there at 55:55 later today` will transform to `I will be there at 57:15 later today`

Comment: @GarbageCollector is `55:55` a valid input? you wrote 24hours format

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple and minimal approach with this pattern :

```
import re
pattern=r'\d{1,2}:\d{2}'
text='I will be there at 4:15 later today'

match=re.findall(pattern,text)
print(match)
```

output:

```
['4:15']
```