# Regular expression for matching both HH:MM and HH:MM:SS time format

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to write a regular expression for matching both HH:MM:SS and MM:SS.

**Match**

- 99:43:22
- 1:43:22
- 01:43:22
- 1:43:22
- 43:22

so I've tried

```
(([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]))|(([0-9]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]))
```

What I wanted to add was just a single OR(|) syntax with two time regex.

But it doesn't match for HH:MM:SS
[image]
what am I missing?
I've already looked into those articles:

- [Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)
- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s06.html
- http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=time&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: _But it doesn't work._ isn't a problem description. What doesn't work? What does it match that it shouldn't? Or what does it not match that it should? Or what errors does it give you?

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: And all your examples are HH:MM:SS, although it's unclear if you wanted to match the first one `99:43:22` or not.

Comment: Change the order of either sides or use `\d\d?:\d\d?(?::\d\d?)?`

Comment: If your problem is that you aren't matching the seconds in `1:43:22`, then just switch the order of the two sub matches in your OR and it should work.

Comment: And if the first one (that starts with `99`) is supposed to be invalid, the easier way to do this would be to just use `TimeSpan.TryParse`

Comment: @MattBurland It works. but I still don't get it. I wonder why it works with just switching the order.

Comment: Because it evaluates each possibility one at a time. Since it's an OR, if the first condition matches, it won't check the second. So you need the stricter condition first.

Comment: @MattBurland ahh.. Now I got it. it's just like a `if(sub-A || sub-B)` code. and the reason of `99` in the examples is because it represents elapsed time such as timer or stopwatch.

Comment: Why downvotes..?

Comment: @MarkChoi: Then you should be aware that you are matching `99:43:22` but not `99:43`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression before the alternation operator is matched before the expression after the alternation operator can even be tested.

If you anchor the start and end of these expressions, like so:

`(^([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]))$|^(([0-9]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$)`

... you should get the behavior you expect.

If you are matching inside of a longer string, then you could put the longest match first:

```
((([0-9]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])|([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])))
```

or rewrite the regex a bit, as follows:

```
((\d{1,2}:)?[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is unclear. From whatever little I understand, I would suggest the following regular expression:

```
^([01]\d?|2[0-4]):[0-5]\d(:[0-5]\d)?$
```

- It makes sure that HH is between 00-24
- It makes sure that MM is between 00-59
- SS is optional (so it can match both HH:MM:SS and HH:MM), and if it
  is there, it is between 00-59

There might be a more efficient method out there, but I can only think of this!