# kendo time picker not setting ng-model when "10:0" like data entered

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-timepicker

`ng-model` is not updating with value when entering "10:0" (not full time, but time picker automatically full fills it). `ng-model` is set undefined.

```
 <input kendo-time-picker 
        class="kendo-block" 
        k-format="'HH:mm'" 
        placeholder="Start Time" 
        required 
        k-ng-model="SP.booking.pickupStartTimeF" 
        name="pickupStartTime" 
        pattern="^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])$" 
        validationmessage="Enter time format" />
```

Comment: Because second part of your regex does not match single 0. It matches 00-19 or 20-23 (which does not make sense for minutes). Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)

Comment: modified patter  to pattern="^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9])$", still model is showing undefined