# JavaScript Time Regex for format H:mm

Tags: javascript, regex, time-format

I have regex for time `/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/`

This validates 24-hr format as well.

What should be the regex if I  **do not want to accept leading zeroes**?

Example:

9:31 not 09:31

> Update:

This issue: [Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format) accepts both with leading and without leading zeroes. But I'm looking for a 24-hr regex that DOES NOT ACCEPT LEADING ZEROES. It's not a duplicate

I tried this:

`^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`

but doesn't accept 0:24

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is : `^([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`

#### I was looking for a regex that does not accept leading zero

Examples:

- 0:30
- 9:30 (not 09:30)
- 0:00 (12 midnight)

https://regex101.com/r/hcjjHN/2

Comment: Wich one is your answer?

Comment: my answer is `^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`. I removed my very first answer to avoid confusion. thank you

Comment: it doesn't. i just tested it using form validation in angular now

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer once again https://regex101.com/r/hcjjHN/2

Answer (score 2):

The second alternation in the capture group matches hours with a leading zero:

```
0[0-9]
```

So, just remove that. You can also make the pattern more DRY by using `1?` instead of the first two alternations, and `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, if you want:

```
^(1?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$
```

https://regex101.com/r/jS9TTj/1

Comment: Thank you. Your second suggestion doesn't accept 24-hr format though. I followed your first suggestion and removed the second alteration.

Comment: See the linked regex101, it looks to work just fine for 24-hour format (just doesn't accept leading zeros, as requested): https://regex101.com/r/jS9TTj/1

Comment: `1?\d` might be more concise, but `\d|1\d` is a little clearer for maintenance sake. :-)