# Create a soccer gametime-related regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to determine the gametime of a soccer match. The gametime can always be written as `mm:ss`. For example, the match starts with `00:00`. More importantly, my regex differs from the hour-limit because the official playing time stops at `90:00`. So, normally `mm` is limited to `([0-5]?\d)`.In addition, I want to make my regex as robust as possible and I want to include the possibility of a lengthy injury-time. In this case, the match can end, for example, at `101:15`. 
The colon-character is always in the middle between the two groups of digits.

With the help of [Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format/7536768) I came up with the following regex:

```
 ^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

How should I change this one to include the possibility of a third digit in the first group of digits, `(m)mm`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the maximum range?

Comment: According to this article the longest match ever lasted 3hours and 23 minutes https://www.theguardian.com/football/2018/mar/29/extra-time-no-end-worlds-longest-match-stockport-doncaster

Comment: Your currently faulty looking regex is probably meant as [`^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$`](https://regex101.com/r/2RrBnC/1/) and would match up to `23:59` maybe you just want to make it something like [`^\d{2,3}:[0-5]\d$`](https://regex101.com/r/2RrBnC/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on the assumption that `199:59` is the maximum time you can have. In other words, when the minutes go to three digits, the leading digit must be a `1` (we never want to show a `0`). That leads to the following regex:

```
^1?[0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZSHWp0/1/)

If you want to support up to `399.59`, that is when the minutes go to three digits the first digit can be a `1`, `2` or `3` (again, we never want to show a `0`), then:

```
^[1-3]?[0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

If you want up to `999.59`:

```
^[1-9]?[0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

Comment: Thanks Booboo for your regex and time

Comment: If I have the number of seconds, how would you convert it back to `mm:ss`? So, what's the "inverse" of your regex?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
^([1-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{1})[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

Comment: So that would match `012:32`. Why would you want three digits for minutes with the leading digit being `0`? What is the difference between what you have and `^[0-9]{2,3}:[0-5][0-9]$`?