# Extracting time with regex from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have scraped some data and there are some hours that have time in 12 hours format. The string is like this:  `Mon - Fri:,10:00 am - 7:00 pm`. So i need to extract the times `10:00 am` and `7:00 pm` and then convert them to 24 hour format. Then the final string I want to make is like this:

```
Mon - Fri:,10:00 - 19:00
```

Any help would be appreciated in this regard. I have tried the following:

```
import re

txt = 'Mon - Fri:,10:00 am - 7:00 pm'
data = re.findall(r'\s(\d{2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))', txt)
print(data)
```

But this regex and any other that I tried to use didn't do the task.

Comment: i cannot find the regex to extract the time from this string. If i get the  regex, i 'll then move forward. I 'll be obliged if u help in generating regex to extract time from this string

Comment: i have posted an attemp

Answer (score 3):

Your regex enforces a whitespace before the leading digit which prevents `,10:00 am` from matching and requires two digits before the colon which fails to match `7:00 pm`. `r"(?i)(\d?\d:\d\d (?:a|p)m)"` seems like the most precise option.

After that, parse the match using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and convert it to military using the `"%H:%M"` [format string](https://strftime.org/). Any invalid times like `10:67` will raise a nice error (if you anticipate strings that should be ignored, adjust the regex to strictly match [24-hour times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format/7536768)).

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

def to_military_time(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x.group(), "%I:%M %p").strftime("%H:%M")

txt = "Mon - Fri:,10:00 am - 7:00 pm"
data = re.sub(r"(?i)(\d?\d:\d\d (?:a|p)m)", to_military_time, txt)
print(data) # => Mon - Fri:,10:00 - 19:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks only for two digit hours (`\d{2}`) with white space before them (`\s`). The following captures also one digit hours, with a possible comma instead of the space.

```
data = re.findall(r'[\s,](\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))', txt)
```

However, you might want to consider all punctuation as valid:

```
data = re.findall(r'[\s!"#$%&\'\(\)*+,-./:;\<=\>?@\[\\\]^_`\{|\}~](\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))', txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex need to change like here.

```
import re

text = 'Mon - Fri:,10:00 am - 7:00 pm'
result = re.match(r'\D* - \D*:,([\d\s\w:]+) - ([\d\s\w:]+)', text)
print(result.group(1))
# it will print 10:00 am
print(result.group(2))
# it will print 7:00 pm
```

You need some thing like '+' and '*' to tell regex to get multiple word, if you only use \s it will only match one character.

You can learn more regex here.

https://regexr.com/

And here you can try regex online.

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) module?

```py
import time
data = "Mon - Fri:,10:00 am - 7:00 pm"
parts = data.split(",")
days = parts[0]
hours = parts[1]
parts = hours.split("-")
t1 = time.strptime(parts[0].strip(), "%I:%M %p")
t2 = time.strptime(parts[1].strip(), "%I:%M %p")
result = days + "," + time.strftime("%H:%M", t1) + " - " + time.strftime("%H:%M", t2)
```

Output:

```
Mon - Fri:,10:00 - 19:00
```