# Regular expressions for pattern matching time format in python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to match following time formats using regular expressions in python and mark True or False whenever the match is found/ not found in a line.  Sample text as below. How can I achieve this task using only regular expressions?

- 2am-8pm
- 2:00am - 8:00pm
- 08:00am-05:00pm
- 5:30am - 8:59pm

One can observe '_am - _pm' and '_am-_pm' patterns that are consistent in every notation.The colons and number format with spaces matching is what I have been attempting to do. below is what I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)

```
HH:MM 12-hour format, optional leading 0, mandatory meridiems (AM/PM)
/((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))/
```

Sample text:

```
Lorem Ipsum is dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry between 2am-8pm. 
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. : False
Lorem has been the industry between 2:00am - 8:00pm standard dummy text since the 1500s. 
It has survived not only five centuries, but also between 08:00am-05:00pm 
It was popularised from 5:30am - 8:59pm with the release of Letraset sheets. 
More recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 983-765-0976.
```

Desired output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry between 2am-8pm. : True
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. : False
Lorem has been the industry between 2:00am - 8:00pm standard dummy text since the 1500s. : True
It has survived not only five centuries, but also between 08:00am-05:00pm : True
It was popularised from 5:30am - 8:59pm with the release of Letraset sheets. : True
More recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 983-765-0976. : False
```

Comment: You only need yet to match the `-` with or without spaces around and then the same time format again. You should show what you have tried (edit the question to show it properly formatted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)(?<!\d)(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]))?\s?[ap]m\s*-\s*(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]))?\s?[ap]m\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NwXXs4/1)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `(?<!\d)` - no digit before is allowed
- `(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]))?`  - time pattern:

  - `(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])` - `0` to `12` with an optional leading `0` before `1-9` digits
  - `(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]))?` - an optional minut sequence with `:` separator
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `[ap]m` - `a` or `p` and then `m`
- `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]))?\s?[ap]m` - the same time pattern as above
- `\b` - word boundary.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/NNJnIk):

```
import re
time = r'(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]))?\s?[ap]m'
pattern = re.compile(r'(?i)(?<!\d){0}\s*-\s*{0}\b'.format(time))
texts = ['Lorem Ipsum is dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry between 2am-8pm.',
'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.',
'Lorem has been the industry between 2:00am - 8:00pm standard dummy text since the 1500s.',
'It has survived not only five centuries, but also between 08:00am-05:00pm',
'It was popularised from 5:30am - 8:59pm with the release of Letraset sheets.',
'More recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 983-765-0976.']
for text in texts:
    print (text, bool(pattern.search(text)), sep=" : ")
```

Output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry between 2am-8pm. : True
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. : False
Lorem has been the industry between 2:00am - 8:00pm standard dummy text since the 1500s. : True
It has survived not only five centuries, but also between 08:00am-05:00pm : True
It was popularised from 5:30am - 8:59pm with the release of Letraset sheets. : True
More recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 983-765-0976. : False
```