# RegExp for HH:MM time format in Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm using the [RegEx from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536768/6618622)

```dart
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$')),
  ],
)
```

This `RegExp` doesn't let me enter anything. Then what should be the correct `RegExp` for time in `HH:MM` format for TextFormField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow` regex, you need to make sure that the pattern can match a single char input.

So, here, you need to use

```
^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?::(?:[0-5]\d?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X10pSW/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])` - an optional `0` or `1` and then any one digit, or `2` and then a digit from `0` to `3`
- `(?::(?:[0-5]\d?)?)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of

  - `:` - a colon
  - `(?:[0-5]\d?)?` - an optional sequence of a digit from `0` to `5` and then an optional digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: A similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71538220/12483095). Would love to see your answer, thanks :)

Comment: @iDecode I do not think that one is specifically unique. Just make sure your pattern matches a single char input. `r'^(?:[+0]9?)?[0-9]{0,12}$'`