# Extracting both 12 and 24 hour time format from a list of different time formats

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I have a list of different time formats  and I want to extract only the HH:MM:SS format in 24 Hour time format. I used regex pattern to do like below

```
import re
from dateutil import parser

time_list = ['7:30 pm', '8:00 pm', '4:00 pm', '4pm. 1', '2 hour', '5 minutes', '1 hour', '30 minutes', 'one hour']
times_form = []
for t in time_list:
    regex = re.compile(r'/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/')
    if regex.match(t):
        dt = parser.parse(t)
        times_form.append(str(dt.hour)+":"+ str(dt.minute)+":"+ str(dt.second))
```

But I am getting None. The expected output is `['19:30:00', '20:00:00', '16:00:00']`

I got the regex pattern from [Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format)

Comment: The `$` at the end of the regex means that the line of text to search must end after the numbers. Try to omit the `$`. And omit the slashes.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Still same. Null list is the result

Comment: I have added that the slashes must be removed, too.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher Just one more doubt. The obtianed result is `['19:30:0', '20:0:0', '16:0:0']` . Why MM and SS that is two zeros are missing.

Comment: When converting a number to a string, by default only the necessary digits are shown. Read about [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) for more fancy formatting.