# Data validation for time input in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, validation, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I am searching for a solution that would allow users to insert time values only in this format: hh:mm, and reject if something else is inserted. Something similar like data validation for date - Data validation -> Is valid date -> Reject input.

I tried to search and adjust a Regexmatch formula for this one, with no success, but I am open for other suggestions also.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "is valid date" will suffice for timestamps within data validation. It will also accept date time though.

Comment: That's a good point and a nice workaround, reasonably assuming that no one would be typing date by mistake in time column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

Perhaps you can try using a more specific `regex` such as the one sample from [this existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536768). Then, apply it your **data validation** via a custom function using [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) function as seen here:

`=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A1),"^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")`

### *Sample Data Validation Config:*

> [image]

### *Demo:*

*E.g. Any text or date formats won't be accepted.*

> [image]

Comment: Hope this one helps. Feel free to reply just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for the provided link!

Comment: I have some problems in using this statement with other in the same range. I would like to combine these two statements in  data validation: 
=if(or(B2=$M$2;B2=$M$3);true;false)
=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(C2);"^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")
Is this possible? Google Sheets deletes a rule when I try to apply other to the same range.

Comment: You can try putting these two functions using [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) like this `=IF(IF(OR(B2=$M$2,B2=$M$3),TRUE,FALSE) = REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(C2),"^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"), TRUE, FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

use custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(""&A1; "\d{2}:\d{2}")
```

if you want to block inputs like: `75:99` then try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(""&A1; "\d{2}:\d{2}")*((A1*1)<=1)
```